# Yaml end ("...") always dumped even if yaml.explicit_end=False

Tags: python, yaml, ruamel.yaml

I am wondering if this is really bug or intention, but anyway.

Why dumping single value always includes explicit YAML end?

```py
import sys
from ruamel.yaml import YAML
yaml=YAML()
yaml.explicit_end=False
yaml.dump(1, sys.stdout)
```

Produces

```
1
...
```

Can the `…` could be somehow easily skipped?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason the document-end-marker (`...`) is added is because the
number is dumped as a *plain* scalar at the root level of the
document. The same happens if you dump a string (assuming that string
can be dumped without quotes without being misinterpreted, i.e. string
consisting of numbers only have to be quoted in order not to be seen
as an integer).

Without document-end-marker, on loading from a stream, the parser
would not know if the document is complete, or the stream just waiting to filled. 
The document-end-marker takes away this ambiguity, so this is intentional, but e.g. when parsing a file (instead of generic stream), that can, and will, also be done by checking for end-of-file.

There are several ways around this, one is to transform the output:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

def strip_document_end_marker(s):
   if s.endswith('...\n'):
       return s[:-4]

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.dump("abc", sys.stdout, transform=strip_document_end_marker)
```

which gives:

```
abc
```

The above should also work with `dump_all` for multiple documents (and the last one being a root level plain scalar).

Another way to achieve this is to reset the `open_ended` attribute after writing a plain value:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()

def wp(self, *args, **kw):
    self.write_plain_org(*args, **kw)
    self.open_ended = False

yaml.Emitter.write_plain_org = yaml.Emitter.write_plain
yaml.Emitter.write_plain = wp
yaml.dump("abc", sys.stdout)
```

which also gives:

```
abc
```

Comment: "Without document-end-marker, on loading from a stream, the parser would not know if the document is complete, or the stream just waiting to filled." That logic cannot be the reason: if you dump `[1, 2, 3]` … you _don't_ get the end marker. Yet a parser sitting at the end of that output similarly cannot determine whether this is the end of the document, or not.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure of the reason but `yaml.dump("1", sys.stdout)` does not print the document's ending marker.

It seems that the serializer appends the three dots ([document's end marker](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2760395)) is append when the Serializer get a non-iterable value:

```
dump(1, stream=sys.stdout)
dump([1], stream=sys.stdout)
dump(datetime.datetime.now(), stream=sys.stdout)
dump("1", stream=sys.stdout)
```

Prints:

```
1
...
[1]
2019-07-09 12:45:27.013202
...
'1'
```

So an easy workaround would be to convert your values to string before dumping them (if possible)...

Comment: The reason `"1"` doesn't print with the document-end-marker is because that string cannot be printed without quotes (as it would be loaded as an integer instead of a string). If you dump `"a"`, you won't get quotes, and so you will get the `...`

Comment: Ah yes, your answer made it clear, thanks! What do you think, should I delete my own answer?

Comment: Just leave it, there is always a chance the OP will like your answer better ;-)

Comment: No, yours is the good one. But I'll leave it for the explanation you gave in your comment :)